# JDBC Java Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to use JDBC to connected my program to a database ... But I have this error :

> Connection refused: connect

I can connect to the database with mysql -u anonymous -P 3306 -h useastdb.ensembl.org

But with JDBC it's not working ...

My code :

```
package com.alpaga.rnmysql;

import java.sql.*;

public class RnMysql {
    public static void main() {
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://useastdb.ensembl.org:3306/xiphophorus_maculatus_rnaseq_95_5", "anonymous", "");
            System.out.print("Database is connected !");
            conn.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Do not connect to DB - Error:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the password of the username?

Comment: There is not password it's just a test database

Comment: Nop it's still not working

Comment: You can connect using `mysql` from the same host you are running this Java code from?

Comment: Are you sure your database is on `useastdb.ensembl.org`, are you sure it is on port 3306, are you sure that you are allowed to access this port on that host (most databases are not accessible over the internet because that is a serious security issue).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have copied the My_Sql connector file in the library of the source code and then try to run it. See the bottom left hand corner in the image provided.

[image]

(from comments) a sample connection code would be :

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  c1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_medical","root","");
  pst=c1.prepareStatement("select Name,Company from product");
  rs=pst.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()) {
    cb1.addItem(rs.getString(1));
    cb2.addItem(rs.getString(2));
  }
} catch(Exception e) { }
```

Comment: Yes I am sure it is.

Comment: You want a sample connection code ???

Comment: try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        c1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_medical","root","");
       
        
        pst=c1.prepareStatement("select Name,Company from product");
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            cb1.addItem(rs.getString(1));
            cb2.addItem(rs.getString(2));    
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        
    }

Comment: I don't have any database on my localhost so I can not use localhost

Comment: To add information, [edit] your answer. Don't add information, especially not code, in comments. Add it to the answer, and use the comment to let a person know that you made the change.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007, and this answer does not address 'connection refused' in any way. If this was the problem it would have been a different exception. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Comment: This is not a solution, because if it where, the op would have received a different error than a Connection refused: connect error. In addition, your example code is mostly cargo culting (eg `newInstance()` is not necessary to load a JDBC driver, and `Class.forName` is not necessary at all in a lot of situations because of JDBC 4 automatic driver loading.